# How to successfully run iOS simulator from Bamboo agent script

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, ios-simulator, xcodebuild, bamboo

I'm trying to run tests using `xcodebuild` through a Bamboo job script task. It opens the simulator, but it stays black and nothing happens, and the script fails due to timeout. **Running the identical `xcodebuild` script goes fine via terminal.** Here's the only related log message I was able to find:

```
Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge
Simulator[30414] <Error>: Unable to determine device.
```

Things I've already tried:

- removing simulator and adding new ones
- checking that bamboo agent is running under default user (which happens to be admin)
- reseting simulator in advance using `xcrun simctl erase`

Answer (score 0):

running `open -a /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/` does the job. [source](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2015/12/managing-ios-continuous-integration-at-enterprise-scale)