# iOS Simulator timeout on Bamboo

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, bamboo, fastlane

As a team we're looking to move away from Jenkins and start using Bamboo for our CI. Our builds are working on the machine running Jenkins. When setting up our new mac to transition to Bamboo the build also works there when run through the command line.

We're running the build using shell `bundle install` then `bundle exec fastlane test` The app builds then exits with: `Exit status: 65` At the start of when it would kick off unit tests

In the logs we find:

`iOSSimulator: Timed out waiting 120 seconds for simulator to boot, current state is 1.`

I've tried `open -a /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/` Suggested in [How to successfully run iOS simulator from Bamboo agent script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402661/how-to-successfully-run-ios-simulator-from-bamboo-agent-script)

I've also tried `xcrun simctl erase` as well we verified that the machine is picking up the same ruby version

Still getting the same error.

Any ideas on other things to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer to this. In the end XCode was installed under a service user but the bamboo agent was run with sudo so it was under root. The root user didn't have XCode so it would crap out when trying to open the simulator.

Comment: So did you give root access to Xcode or something else?

Comment: Since this was a new instance we just un installed bamboo and reinstalled it under the service user. 

I would assume you could give root access to XCode to solve the problem though